# How to convert string into Time object in Java?

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I have String value of **08:03:10 pm**, and I want to convert it into **time**. How can I do this in Java?

Comment: Thats such a common question, it could have been asked 10 times this week. :) I am guessing google is broken again.

Comment: In fact it looks like Chamal has asked this twice today.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion). Even closer duplicate is [Convert Java string to Time, NOT Date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18604408/642706).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
 String str = "08:03:10 pm";
 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
 Date date = formatter.parse(str);
```

- [IDE One demo](http://ideone.com/cnN99)

**Must See**

- [API Doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: dont forget to convert date to java.sql.Time.

Comment: well, chamal want time not date.. although java.sql.Time is a thin wrapper around date, it is better abstraction for time .

Comment: I would also suggest conversion to Time (i.e. : `Time time =  new Time(date.getTime())` ) because of 2 reasons : 1 - OP has specifically  asked for a `Time` object instead of a `Date` object ,and 2(which back up 1) -  maybe he has some bad API, which can not be changed(e.g. : `Time getTime(String s)` - it cannot return a `Date` , because it will result in a compiler error).

Comment: Casting `formatter.parse(str)` to `Date` is redundant.

Answer (score 6):

If you omit the [period](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1468860/53236), it is very easy. Just call the `java.sql.Time.valueof()` method instead of the `Time time = new Time("20:03:10");` method.

Answer (score 1):

Time does not have a contractor that takes long so use `time.set(date.getTime())`