# convert array objects into time

Tags: java

If i have an **Array** which contains the Strings **07:46:30 pm , 10:45:28 pm  , 07:23:39 pm** , .......

and I want to convert it into **Time**. How can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string into Time.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584994/convert-string-into-time)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to convert an array of Strings in the given format to an array of dates:

```
public static Date[] toDateArray(final String[] dateStrings)
throws ParseException{
    final Date[] arr = new Date[dateStrings.length];
    int pos = 0;
    final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm:ss a");
    for(final String input : dateStrings){
        arr[pos++] = df.parse(input);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the SimpleDateFormat class.  Here is an example:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
for(String str : array){
    Date date = formatter.parse(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the SimpleDateFormat class to parse the date.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own parser. See this example:

http://www.kodejava.org/examples/101.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want a array or list of time...

```
String[] arrString = new String[] { "07:46:30 pm", "10:45:28 pm", "07:23:39 pm" }

Time[] arrTime = new Time[strArray.lengh];
```

or

```
List<Time> listTime = new ArrayList<Time>();
```

Array string to array or list time:

```
//For array
for (int i = 0; i < arrString.length; i++) {
   DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
   Date date = formatter.parse(arrString[i]);

   //Populate the ARRAY
   arrTime[i] = new Time(date.getTime());
}

//For list
for (String str : arrString) {
   DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
   Date date = formatter.parse(str);

   //Populate the LIST
   listTime.add(new Time(date.getTime()));
}
```