# Convert Java string to Time, NOT Date

Tags: java, string, date, time

I would like to convert a variable string to a Time type variable, not Date using Java. the string look like this 17:40

I tried using the code below but this instance is a date type variable not time

```
String fajr_prayertime  =       prayerTimes.get(0);
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
fajr_begins = (Date)formatter.parse(fajr_prayertime);
System.out.println(" fajr time " + fajr_begins);
```

However Netbean complains that I should insert an exception as below;

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
try {
fajr_begins = (Date)formatter.parse(fajr_prayertime);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(JavaFXApplication4.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
System.out.println(" fajr time " + fajr_begins);
```

Any idea how I can get the time out of the string above.

Comment: What format is the original `String` in? ... Also, Java doesn't have a `Time` object, other then `java.sql.Time`...

Comment: what is time? `java.sql.Time`?

Comment: the time come from ArrayList<String> prayerTimes  String fajr_prayertime  =       prayerTimes.get(0);

Comment: I don't know what you mean Nachok, but I am getting a string similar to i.e. 15:30 and would like to convert this string to a time so that I can compare it say if time > 15:30 then...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
java.sql.Time timeValue = new java.sql.Time(formatter.parse(fajr_prayertime).getTime());
```

Comment: I get the following, unreported exception parseexception, must be caught or declared to be thrown, do I really have to create an exception for this!!

Comment: You do have to catch, or propogate, the exception.  No need to create an exception though.  Note that you don't *have* to do anything with the exception, but if you don't, incorrect input will be silently ignored, leading to headaches later.  I recommend logging it as the original code sample does.

Answer (score 22):

You might consider [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) or [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html), which has a type called [`LocalTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) specifically for a time of day without a date component.

Example code in Joda-Time 2.7/Java 8.

```
LocalTime t = LocalTime.parse( "17:40" ) ;
```

Answer (score 6):

You might want to take a look at this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String myTime = "10:30:54";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = sdf.parse(myTime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String formattedTime = sdf.format(date);

    System.out.println(formattedTime);

}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
try {

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a"); //if 24 hour format
    // or
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"); // 12 hour format

    java.util.Date d1 =(java.util.Date)format.parse(your_Time);

    java.sql.Time ppstime = new java.sql.Time(d1.getTime());

} catch(Exception e) {

    Log.e("Exception is ", e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following code for changing the String value into the time equivalent:

```
 String str = "08:03:10 pm";
 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
 Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(str);
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 4):

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM");
simpleDateFormat.format(fajr_prayertime);
```

Answer (score 2):

## Joda-Time & java.time

Both [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) and [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) (new in Java 8) offer a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) class to represent a time-of-day without any date or time zone.

Example code, identical code for both *java.time* and *Joda-Time*.

```
LocalTime localTime = new LocalTime( "14:40" );
LocalTime deadline = new LocalTime( "15:30" );
boolean meetsDeadline = localTime.isBefore( deadline );
```

---

[image]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

try...

```
 java.sql.Time.valueOf("10:30:54");
```

Comment: FYI, the `java.sql.Time` class has been supplanted by the [`java.time.LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) class, as of the adoption of JSR 310.

Answer (score -1):

String to Time (using an arbitrary time):

```
String myTime = "10:00:00"; 
Time startingTime = new Time (myTime);
```

String to Time (using currentTime):

```
String currentTime = getCurrentTime(); 
Time startingTime = new Time (currentTime);
```

Time to String:

```
private String getCurrentTime() {    
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("kkmmss");
    String currentTime = dateFormat.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
    return currentTime;
}
```

Comment: What class is `Time`? Please mention library and link to doc.

Comment: When I create Time startingTime; - Eclipse offers the option to Import 'Time' (android.text.format)

Comment: Time constructor receives a long, not a String

Comment: Android Edition is not the standard java so your code will not work.