# Javascript Date for java.sql.Time

Tags: javascript, java, date, time

Is it possible to adjust the JavaScript `Date` string value to format of `java.sql.Time`. I can't seem to find a correct solution for this.

Thanks!

Comment: what format does `java.sql.Time` have?

Comment: What do you mean with the "format of `java.sql.Time`"? A `java.sql.Time` object does not have a format by itself.

Comment: I want to be able to send a string value which is accepted by the `Time` class

Comment: send a string and parse it to Time 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604408/convert-java-string-to-time-not-date

Comment: Do you mean a string for `Time.valueOf(String)`? If so, the format should be `hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: I'm sending a string with a value from frontend to my api and the api has a field of type `java.sql.Time.`

Comment: If you can, avoid the outdated `java.sql.Time` class and prefer the modern `java.time.LocalTime` (or `OffsetTime`)  instead. Of course, if it’s an API you cannot change, you need to convert to the class the API expects.

Comment: @OleV.V. there is one problem. Some of the date fields in the database have only time and some have only date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should serialize you object on server side:
es. `@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ")`

and then on the client side you could use moment.js:

```
moment(stringDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ').toDate();
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for. Unfortunately I cannot set the @Оsonformat, because some of the database rows contain invalid formatted Date objects and that will bring in exceptions.

Comment: By corrupt date object I've meant that some dates have only time and some have only date without time.

Answer (score -1):

**this is how to convert to sql date format**

```
var date;
    date = new Date();
    date = date.getUTCFullYear() + '-' +
            ('00' + (date.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
            ('00' + date.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) + ' ' +
            ('00' + date.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ':' +
            ('00' + date.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' +
            ('00' + date.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);
```

Comment: The questions was about `java.sql.Time`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530012/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-java-sql-date                                                                                                      refer above link