# How to print Time from string?

Tags: java, android

I want to print time from string, i have follow this code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String time = "15:30:18";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse(time);
        Log.e("Time", String.valueOf(date));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Time : " + date , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}
but the ouput is Thu Jan 01 15:30:18 GMT+07:00 1970, 
i just want 15:30:18, 
anyone can help me ?

Comment: Quick question, if you have the string that you are parsing, why are you casting to a Date object and then back to string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Java string to Time, NOT Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604408/convert-java-string-to-time-not-date)

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use format method

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
   try {
      String time = "15:30:18";
        Date date = sdf.parse(time);
        System.out.println("Time : " + sdf.format(date) );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

See this link for more information https://stackabuse.com/how-to-get-current-date-and-time-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

If you want a string time

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse(time);
        String time = String.valueOf(date).split(" ")[3];
        Log.e("Time", sdf.format(date));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Time : " + time , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

else if you want time object result you can simply do like this

```
 try {
        Log.e(TAG, "Time" +Time.valueOf(time)  );

    }catch (IllegalStateException ex )
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "wrong time format" );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## `java.time.LocalTime`

You are using the wrong class. `Date` represents a moment, a date with time-of-day in UTC. And that terrible class is now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

The `LocalTime` class represents a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
String input = "15:30:18" ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( input ) ;
```

## ISO 8601

Create a string in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output1 = lt.toString() ;
```

> 15:30:18

## Localize

Create a string in localized format.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( Locale.US ) ;
String output2 = lt.format( f ) ;
```

> 3:30:18 PM

Localize to Québec, just for fun.

```
DateTimeFormatter fQuébec = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;
String output3 = lt.format( fQuébec ) ;
```

> 15 h 30 min 18 s

See all this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/M4MnjK).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).